# indexing in Sublime Text 3

Tags: indexing, sublimetext3

I started using Sublime Text 3 recently, I face a small issue that annoys me sublime text keep indexing files under `node_modules` and `bower_components` even after I excluded them in user settings:

```
{
    "color_scheme": "Packages/1337 Color Scheme/1337.tmTheme",
    "ignored_packages":
    [
        "Vintage"
    ],
    "binary_file_patterns": [".idea/*", "bower_components/*", "node_modules/*"],
    "index_files": true,
    "index_exclude_patterns": [".idea/*", "bower_components/*", "node_modules/*"],
}
```

The above configuration removed the excluded folders from `Goto Anything` but I still can find text inside files under those folders `Find in Folder...`, please advice.

Another Question, how can I reset indexing in sublime text.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try `**` instead of `*` (to match sub directories too), e.g.

```
"binary_file_patterns": [".idea/**", "bower_components/**", "node_modules/**"],
```

Works for me in ST3 build 3114

Comment: There is no such thing as globstar operator `**` in Sublime's file patterns. Saving settings file, which triggered refresh maybe helped? There is a lot of posts about `**`. Maybe there really once was `**`? A pattern becomes "dir" pattern and will try to match also dirs once you use '/' in it. Then * at the end is implied and it makes no difference if you do `.../` `.../*` or `.../**`, which is just two '*' (anything or nothing twice) https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/file_patterns.html